# how to bring application to resume state when sms navigation back is pressed from phone sms screen?

Tags: android

In some activity I'm opening phone SMS screen and sending message after sending SMS.

When I click on navigation back (top) button from SMS screen it is going to back to inbox screen. But I want my application to resume from background when top navigation button is clicked.

Can we have the control over SMS screen navigation key in Android? If yes, can anyone tell me how to control and handle on click to resume the application?

Below is code use to fire the intent for SMS:

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("smsto: %s", phoneNo)));
        smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
```

How to achieve this?
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If it's the back button from within the SMS application, than I'm afraid you don't have access to it and cannot change the behavior. But it should work with the back button from the navigation bar (if it helps in any way).